# Convert html tags to string php

Tags: php, html, render

I have been trying to do the following for a long time and haven't been able to figure it out.

I have an string in php which contains html in it like follows for example:

```
$var = "<div style="display:inline">how</div>
        <div style="display:none">are</div>
        <div style="display:inline">you</div>
        ?";
```

and would like to store in another string $var2, "howyou?";
Basically, i'd like to render the html in php in a sense.

How do i go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Ooh, not a project I'd like to take on. In steps: (1) load it in DOMDocument or something (2) search all nodes with `style` attributes (3) parse the css in those attributes (4) delete node based on result of that parsing if needed (5) collapse all whitespace of nodes which have a default `whitespace:normal` (6) get textContent.

Comment: So as i see it, there is no prewritten libraries or extensions i can use to do this? I would have to do it manually?

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I don't understand why you want to generate HTML this way. Is it a requirement? Is it a small part of a larger project? You might get better help if you explained your goals some more.

Comment: @ShiggySteez: not that I know of, they may be out there, but I would expect them to take if further then you want (color, position etc.). There are parts available to do this of course, php css parsers a plenty for instance, pick the one you like ;)

Comment: It is definitely for a larger project as this in and of itself wouldn't be all that useful.  I could go in detail about the project, but i think its overkill in this scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ' instead of " inside any string 
like that:

```
$var = "<div style='display:inline'>how</div>
        <div style='display:none'>are</div>
        <div style='display:inline'>you</div>
        ?";
```

It must work now

Answer (score 0):

First, erase the line with the `display:none` using [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and then use [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to get rid of the other html tags

```
$var = '<div style="display:inline">how</div>
        <div style="display:none">are</div>
        <div style="display:inline">you</div>
        ?';

$pattern = '/.*display:none.*/';

$var2 = strip_tags( preg_replace($pattern, '', $var) );
```

Comment: Thanks Ghilas. I guess i will go with this route since there doesn't seem to be another easy way out of it.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to render it, you could [parse the HTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
$dom = str_get_html('<div style="display:inline;">how</div>
    <div style="display:none">are</div>
    <div style="display:inline">you</div>
    ?');

$invisible = $dom->find('[style*=display:none]');
$stripped_html = $dom->outertext;

foreach($invisible as $node)
{
    $stripped_html = str_replace($node->outertext, "", $stripped_html);
}

echo str_replace(" ", "", str_get_html($stripped_html)->plaintext);
```

results in

```
howyou?
```

Comment: This isn't really n answer - there's no explanation of what you intend, or how it answers the OP.

Comment: Of course it is, the link instantly shows the capabilities - accessing any property of a HTML node, what is exactly how one could go about this.

Comment: Actually, no. There's a lot more to this than extracting a few nodes. See Wrikken's comment above.

Comment: I understand your answer cookie, but i know how to parse it.  In fact i parsed it with xpath to get to this point.  Now i need to get the remaining node's html output.

Comment: @ShiggySteez please check out the code - is that not the first step to what you wanted?

Answer (score -2):

I think you set up $var wrongly, you need to escape those inner "s

and simply use strip_tags() if you need the complete content

```
$var = "<div style=\"display:inline\">how</div>
        <div style=\"display:none\">are</div>
        <div style=\"display:inline\">you</div>
        ?";

echo strip_tags($var);
```

the result:

> how are you ?

Comment: The escaping of the quotes is not an issue as this was simply as an example, but thx for that anyway.  However i don't want all the content without the tags, i want the styles of the tags to take effect.  So for example the display:none ones to not show up at all

Comment: It Didn't answer to the question

Comment: oh I see, I misread it. In that case you'll have to do it manually.